# flattening XML to load via SSIS package

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis, transform

I have an XML output from Lotus Notes DB. Following is the XML structure:

```
<Exec>
   <project id='C000253' type='Approved' >
      <DaysInOnHold>39</DaysInOnHold>
      <DaysInCompleted>0</DaysInCompleted>
      <ProjectComplexity type='1280'>Complex</ProjectComplexity>
      <ChangeRequest>
         <OnGoingAmt type='768'>-112</OnGoingAmt>
         <EAmt type='768'>123</EAmt>
      </ChangeRequest>
      <ChangeRequest>
         <ItemNbr type='768'>2</ItemNbr>
         <EAmt type='768'>321</EAmt>
      </ChangeRequest>
      <IncidentalItem>
         <ACost type='768'>0</ACost>
         <Billable type='1280'>Billable</Billable>
      </IncidentalItem>
      <IncidentalItem>
         <ACost type='768'>33</ACost>
         <Billable type='1280'>Billable</Billable>
      </IncidentalItem>
      <MaterialItem>
         <AQty type='768'>1</AQty>
         <ItemNbr type='768'>4</ItemNbr>
      </MaterialItem>
      <MaterialItem>
         <AQty type='768'>0</AQty>
         <ItemNbr type='768'>5</ItemNbr>
      </MaterialItem>
   </project>
   <project id='C110011' type='Not Approved'>
     ...
      ...
   </project>
</Exec>
```

When I load the XML source in my SSIS package, it creates a table for every column name, which of-course is not very desirable.

I would like to transform this in such a way that it gives me the ability to have a Project table, MaterialItem and ChangeRequest tables (which would subsequently be related back to the individual project entry.

Would XSLT be an answer? If so, any help would be appreciated.

I thought I'd add in what the desired output should be (seems that all the type attributes are causing the issues). So seems that i need a transform that would get rid of all the attributes - specifically the type="...."

```
<Exec>
   <project id='C0001111'>
      <DaysInOnHold>33</DaysInOnHold>
      <DaysInCompleted>0</DaysInCompleted>
      <ProjectComplexity>Complex</ProjectComplexity>
      <ChangeRequest>
         <OnGoingAmt>52</OnGoingAmt>
         <EAmt>123</EAmt>
      </ChangeRequest>
      <ChangeRequest>
         <ItemNbr>2</ItemNbr>
         <EAmt>321</EAmt>
      </ChangeRequest>
      <IncidentalItem>
         <ACost>0</ACost>
         <Billable>Not Billable</Billable>
      </IncidentalItem>
      <IncidentalItem>
         <ACost>33</ACost>
         <Billable>Billable</Billable>
         </IncidentalItem>
      <MaterialItem>
         <AQty>1</AQty>
         <ItemNbr>4</ItemNbr>
      </MaterialItem>
      <MaterialItem>
         <AQty>0</AQty>
         <ItemNbr>5</ItemNbr>
      </MaterialItem>
   </project>
</Exec>
```

Comment: XSLT could indeed be the answer here, if you want to transform the XML into a different structure. But first you need to know what structure you require. If do already know what you need to transform to, could you edit your question to show a sample of the XML you expect to be output? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is straight-forward with XSLT. Firstly, you need to read up on the XSLT [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) which on its own will copy all the nodes and attributes in your XSLT as is.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to remove just **type** attributes, but leave other attributes intact, just add the following template to the above XSLT. This will match **type** attributes, but output nothing (i.e. they will be ignored)

```
<xsl:template match="@type" />
```

If you want to remove ALL attributes, simply amend the indentity transform template to remove the match on attributes. For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hmm everything worked perfectly, except I have one more problem. Seems that at times the child elements i.e. ChangeRequest or IncidentalItem may be jumbled up and not in order. The order of elements may be ChangeRequest, ChangeRequest, IncidentalItem, ChangeRequest <--- if this occurs, then I have an issue in my SSIS package. Is there a way to sort inner children based on their element name as such? so that I have consistency?

Comment: Yes. You would have a template to match the **project** element, then call **xsl:apply-templates** on the children with a **xsl:sort** parameter specified (sorting on "local-name()). Check out http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/07/03/transform.html for some examples of sorting. If you can't quite get it to work, it's probaby best to ask a whole new question, now this one has been marked as accepted. That's perfectly fine to ask more questions. Thanks!