# reorder XML elements or set an explicit template with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis

I tried the solution in my previous question ([flattening XML to load via SSIS package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493789/flattening-xml-to-load-via-ssis-package)), however this isn't working. I now know what I need to do, however I need some guidance on how to do it.

So say I have the following XML structure:

```
<person id="1">
   <name>John</name>
   <surname>Smith</surname>
   <age>25</age>
   <comment>
      <comment_id>1</comment_id>
      <comment_text>Hello</comment_text>
   </comment>
   <comment>
      <comment_id>2</comment_id>
      <comment_text>Hello again!</comment_text>
   </comment>
   <somethingelse>
       <id>1</id>
   </somethingelse>
   <comment>
      <comment_id>3</comment_id>
      <comment_text>Third Item</comment_text>
   </comment>
</person>
<person id="2">
   <name>John</name>
   <surname>Smith</surname>
   <age>25</age>
   <somethingelse>
       <id>1</id>
   </somethingelse>
</person>
...
...
```

If I am to load this into a SSIS package, as an XML source, what I will essentially get is a table created for each element, as opposed to get a structured table output such as

- person table (name, surname, age)
- somethingelse table (id)
- comment table (comment_id, comment_text)

What I end up getting is:

- person table (person_Id <-- internal SSIS id)
- name table
- surname table
- age table
- person_name table
- person_surname table
- person_comment_comment_id table

etc...

What I found was that if each  element and all inner elements are not in the same format and consistency, i will get the above anomaly which makes it rather complex especially if I am dealing with 80 - 100+ columns.

Unfortunately I have no way of modifying the system (Lotus Notes) that produces these reports, so I was wondering whether I may be able to **explicitly** have an XSLT template that will be able to align each **person** sub elements (and the sub collection elements such as **comments** ? Unless there is a quicker way to realign all inner elements.

Seems that SSIS XML source requires a very consistent XML file in the sense of: if the **name** element is in position 1, then all subsequent **name** elements within **person** parent have to be in position 1.

SSIS seems to pickup the inconsistencies if there are certain elements missing from one **parent** to another, however, if their ordering is not right (A, B, C)(A, B, C)(A,C,B), it will chuck a massive fuss!

All help is appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: +1 for the exemplary question setup alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want a specific order for the children of `<person>`. See if the following XSLT is close to what you're after:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <!-- XSLT identity transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="surname"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="age"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="somethingelse"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="comment"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Output XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <person id="1">
    <name>John</name>
    <surname>Smith</surname>
    <age>25</age>
    <somethingelse>
      <id>1</id>
    </somethingelse>
    <comment>
      <comment_id>1</comment_id>
      <comment_text>Hello</comment_text>
    </comment>
    <comment>
      <comment_id>2</comment_id>
      <comment_text>Hello again!</comment_text>
    </comment>
    <comment>
      <comment_id>3</comment_id>
      <comment_text>Third Item</comment_text>
    </comment>
  </person>
  <person id="2">
    <name>John</name>
    <surname>Smith</surname>
    <age>25</age>
    <somethingelse>
      <id>1</id>
    </somethingelse>
  </person>
</project>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much. I have last question - is there a way to explicitly state the children elements that have sub-elements too? i.e. **somethingelse** seems that some of the sub-elements inner elements are also jumbled up and not in order from record to record. (by the way i can now see my person elements!

Comment: Yes, you can order the children of <somethingelse> as well. Copy the <xsl:template match="person"> tree and replace the root element with <xsl:template match="somethingelse">. In the new tree, keep <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>, but replace the other <xsl:apply-templates> elements with the child elements of <somethingelse> you want to order.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to include a manual definition of how to order things, you could simply order them alphabetically.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort data-type="text" select="name()" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This way output order would be predictable and stable, but `<name>` for example would end up somewhere in the middle, after `<comment>`. I don't know if that's all-right with SSIS, but I guess it should be.

---

EDIT: If you want to sort dependent tables (i.e. elements that contain children instead of just text) to the bottom... Well, `<xsl:sort>` can be applied more than once.

```
  <xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="boolean(*)" />
        <xsl:sort data-type="text" select="name()" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Where `boolean(*)` effectively converts the fact "children" / "no children" to `true` / `false`, which in turn (in numerical context, due to `data-type="number"`) is represented as `0` / `1`. This way the text-only elements end up before everything else.